# Average from the product of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a invoice detail table that contains at a minimum for this discussion, the item id, the quantity sold, and the price sold. I need to know the average sell price for the item.

Sample data:

```
Id      Quantity     Price
----    ---------    ------
7       2            10.00
7       3            30.00
```

The data I am trying to get would basically be ((2 * 10.00) + (3 * 30)) / 5 = 22

Comment: Be interesting to see what you have already tried...

Comment: And please also show your expected result

Comment: @Squirrel my expected result is in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
--Create data
create table #t1 (Id int, Quantity int, Price decimal(5,2));

insert into #t1 values (7,2,10.00)
insert into #t1 values (7,3,30.00)

--Query
select t.id,
        sum(Quantity*Price)/sum(Quantity)
from #t1 as t
group by t.id
```

Comment: sum(quantity * price) / sum(quantity) worked. I was trying sum((quantity * price) / sum(quantity). SQL didn't like the nested aggregates. Thanks for your help.